# Adjusting heights for flex items

Tags: javascript, html, css, flexbox, height

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  let button = document.querySelector("button");

  button.addEventListener("click", ev => {
    let main = document.querySelector("main");
    let box2 = document.createElement("div");
    let box1 = document.querySelector(".box1");

    box2.innerHTML = "<p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur? Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur? Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur? Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur? Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?</p>"

    box2.classList.add("box2");

    box2.classList.add("smallerWidth");
    box1.classList.add("smallerWidth");

    main.style.display = "flex";
    main.insertAdjacentElement("afterbegin", box2);

    ev.target.disabled = true;
  });
});
```

```css
.box1 {
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 5px;
}

.box2 {
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 5px;
  overflow: auto;
}

.smallerWidth {
  width: 45%;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <div class="box1">
    <p>"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
      dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."</p>

    <p>Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui
      dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur? Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem.
      Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum
      qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?</p>

    <button>CLICK HERE</button>
  </div>
</main>
```

In the above code, there is a `div` with text and a button. If you click on the button, the `main` section is changed to a `flex` area and another `div` containing text is created and appears left of `div1`.

Let's say that the two divs (`box1` and `box2`) can vary dynamically with how much text each contains. How can I make it so that `box1`'s height is as small as possible (i.e. only tall enough to contain the text which can vary in length and button) and `box2`'s height is no greater than that of `box1`? If `box2` contains more text than can appear in its height, the scrollbar is added (hence, the overflow auto property defined on it).

Comment: I think that I have found a solution on Stack Overflow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38852811/create-a-row-of-flexbox-items-with-a-max-height-defined-by-one-child/38852981#38852981.

Answer (score 0):

Add `height: 100%` into `.smallerWidth` class and than you can detect which box is smaller and use it's height to set height of the other:

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  let button = document.querySelector("button");

  button.addEventListener("click", ev => {
    let main = document.querySelector("main");
    let box2 = document.createElement("div");
    let box1 = document.querySelector(".box1");

    box2.innerHTML = "<p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur? Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur? Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur? Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur? Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?</p>"

    box2.classList.add("box2");

    box2.classList.add("smallerWidth");
    box1.classList.add("smallerWidth");

    main.style.display = "flex";
    main.insertAdjacentElement("afterbegin", box2);
// set height to match smalest box
    if (box1.scrollHeight > box2.scrollHeight)
      box1.style.height = box2.scrollHeight + "px";
    else
      box2.style.height = box1.scrollHeight + "px";

    ev.target.disabled = true;
  });
});
```

```css
.box1 {
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 5px;
}

.box2 {
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 5px;
  overflow: auto;
}

.smallerWidth {
  width: 45%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <div class="box1">
    <p>"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
      dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."</p>

    <p>Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui
      dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur? Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem.
      Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum
      qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?</p>

    <button>CLICK HERE</button>
  </div>
</main>
```

Comment: But how would I get it so that `box2` is the same height as `box1` and therefore makes uses of the scroll bar (via `overflow: auto`)?

Comment: @JeremyStryer I've updated the code, hope it's what's you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks for that update! However, giving either `box1` or `box2` a fixed height seems to defeat the purpose of using `flexbox`. As the height of the initial box changes when the viewport is increased or decreased, the height of the other box stays the same. Looking for a way to make the boxes always have same height (box with more content should have scroll bar).

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I found the solution in another SO thread. The key is to have an inner element that has absolute position within the flex item that has more content (and therefore the scroll bar): stackoverflow.com/questions/38852811/…